# dark-mode Code of Conduct page footer is light on sites with dark-mode support

Tags: bug, status-completed, code-of-conduct, footer, dark-mode

Sites with dark mode usually have a black footer with light text, but in the Code of Conduct pages, the footer is light background color with light text.

Sample screenshot from [Stack Overflow Code of Conduct page](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct)'s footer:

> [image: Stack Overflow Code of Conduct footer with dark mode]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for letting us know about this bug. It was, as correctly deduced [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/398302/344828), a specificity issue. Rather than edit the files (which are used in a bunch of places), I just removed the product css from that page and pulled in only what was necessary to keep the typefaces consistent. This fix is live now, please let me know if you notice any issues with it, and thanks again!

Answer (score 8):

Helping the developers a bit, I found the root cause: the Code of Conduct page is loading [`product.css`](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/Product/product.css) file, which overrides the footer style, and is not loaded in the ordinary Stack Overflow pages.

Quick fix is to just remove the override there, as it's already defined in `primary.css` however I can't know other implications it might have, of course.

Comment: Greatly appreciate the help. I'm sure it will save our devs some time.

Comment: Afaict, `product.css` only affects the font in the title and lede (in light mode).

Comment: This did indeed save me some time, thank you!